# Can getline() be skipped w/o user input?

Tags: c++, while-loop, getline

**Edit**

The issue was that I was using `cin >>` at another point in my program, and so there was a trailing newline in the stream buffer.

---

So the main question is about getline(), but in order to put it into perspective you have to see my code first. For some odd reason, when I run my program, it runs through the loop perfectly fine the first time. Yet the second time it skips my `getline(cin, inputMenu)` statment. And yes I know this is a very very basic program, and I know there are no other errors with it as I've tested literally every other aspect of it. Is there something about `getline()` that I don't know?

```
while (1)
   {
      // Reset the input each loop
      inputMenu = "ABC";

      // Menu
      cout << "Menu\n  P (Purchase)\n  S (Shut down)" << "\n\n  You decide: ";

      /* I put this if statement as a test, to make sure that it always runs getline.
         But for some odd reason when I run it I get this (see run below)*/
      if(1)
      getline(cin, inputMenu);

      //Blah blah all the other stuff if they enter a P or S. (Not an infinite  loop)

         cout << "\nYou just earned " << inputYogurt << " stamps!"
            << " Bringing your grand total to " << numStamps << "!\n" << endl;
      }
   }


---------------------- Run --------------------
Menu
  P (Purchase)
  S (Shut down)

  You decide: p

How many yogurts would you like to buy? 3

You just earned 3 stamps! Bringing your grand total to 3!


Menu
  P (Purchase)
  S (Shut down)

  You decide: Menu     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Thats my error
  P (Purchase)
  S (Shut down)

  You decide:

-------------------------------------------------------
```

It skips the getline() statement and just runs the loop again. Maybe I don't understand getline() well enough, because clearly that seems to be the issue. I thought that when you use getline, it must wait for user input, am I wrong?

Comment: there is a problem in your loop, its endless!!

Comment: @vishal lol i know its endless. I have an if statement in there that breaks out of the loop

Comment: no it does not break the loop

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happens. The only way to deal with is to call `cin.get()` before `cin.getline()`. There is another method to call `cin.flush()` before `cin.getline()`, but it may not work.

```
while (1)
   {
      // Reset the input each loop
      inputMenu = "ABC";

      // Menu
      cout << "Menu\n  P (Purchase)\n  S (Shut down)" << "\n\n  You decide: ";

      /* I put this if statement as a test, to make sure that it always runs getline.
         But for some odd reason when I run it I get this (see run below)*/


      cin.get(); // add extra input
      getline(cin, inputMenu);

      //Blah blah all the other stuff if they enter a P or S.

         cout << "\nYou just earned " << inputYogurt << " stamps!"
            << " Bringing your grand total to " << numStamps << "!\n" << endl;
      }
   }
```

or try to use

```
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');

getline(cin, inputMenu);
```

Comment: still didn't work :'(      I was thinking of using `cin >>`, but I don't have enough knowledge of it/know if you can even apply it to a string.

Comment: you can experiment with adding another extra cin.get() or cin.flush()

Comment: or just use gets or scanf

Comment: `cin >>` can be applied to the string but it inputs only first word before whitespace